# Why is bad my Excel formula?

Tags: excel

This formula is not being allowed in Excel:

```
=if(C2="NULL","False","True")
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

**NOTE:** Here you can see the content of the columns:

[image]

**NOTE2:** This is the error being shown:

[image]

Comment: Are you actually looking for the word `NULL`? or empty cells with no value at all?

Comment: I'm trying to find the word `NULL`. I attached an image showing what I have in my C2 column.

Comment: Looks fine... what do you mean by `not being allowed`?

Comment: does you local settings use `;` instead of `,` for the delimiter?  The formula works for me.

Comment: scot, that was it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in ","
Try to use ";" instead of ","
=IF(C2="NULL";"False";"True")